# Spring MVC - Adding multiple markers to Google Map from the database

Tags: javascript, java, spring, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to display multiple markers on a map from my database. I have looked at other examples and have Google's examples working on my server, but can't seem to get it working with database information.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple Map</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/project" user="root" password="root" />

<sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
SELECT * from House;
</sql:query>

<div id="map"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var markerLat, markerLong;
    markerLat = [
        <c:forEach var="s" items="${result.rows}">
            <c:out value="${s.lat}"/>,
        </c:forEach>;
    markerLong = [
      <c:forEach var="s" items="${result.rows}">
          <c:out value="${s.lng}"/>,
      </c:forEach>;

    function initialize() {
        var map;
        var initlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(markerLat[0],markerLong[0]);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 6,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(36,5),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); 
        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < markerLat.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(markerLat[i], markerLong[i]),
                map: map
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(markers[i]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        }
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBiKZEYI58kG67y8dT50HG4ByxMmWHbwXA"
    async defer></script>
```

It is giving me an error saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined"

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or direct me to other examples of adding multiple markers to a map from a database?

Comment: Try to move your first <script> ...</script> before the <body>...</body>.

Comment: @jmj No still showing the same error unfortunately.

Comment: ok your problem is disappeared after removing callback parameter from the googleapis.com url but now this is a syntax issue check your code.

Comment: @Bolzano Yeah that error is now gone too. It is now saying that google has not been defined. I will edit the post now.

Comment: Try to move your **second** <script> ...</script> before the <body>...</body>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is loading the Google Maps javascript API asynchronously:

```
<script
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBiKZEYI58kG67y8dT50HG4ByxMmWHbwXA"
async defer></script>
```

You should either:

A. load the Google Maps Javascript API synchronously:

1. remove the "async defer" from the script include
2. load the Google Maps Javascript API prior to using the `google.maps` namespace.

B. load it asynchronously and use the `callback` parameter to execute the code that depends on it once it has loaded:

1. remove this line `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);`
2. change the API include to:

```
<script
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBiKZEYI58kG67y8dT50HG4ByxMmWHbwXA
&callback=initialize"
async defer></script>
```

Comment: Tried both of these methods but it's still returning the same error message.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue in your question so we can see what the problem actually is.

Comment: I got it working just there. There was a small problem with the CSS, another problem with a closing bracket on the array and your suggestion helped as well. Thanks a lot.